# How can i get the last post from wp multisite?

Tags: wp-query, multisite, php, blog-id

I have to get the last post from my Multisite network on WordPress. For now I use this code for display the last updated post after a cycle on each `blog_id`:

```
<?php

$blogs = get_last_updated(' ', 0, 1);
foreach ($blogs AS $blog);
    switch_to_blog($blog["blog_id"]);
        $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=1&orderby=date');
        foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
```

But if I want to get the last post -- not the last post updated -- how can I do that? Because if I change and refresh a post I get the post like the last on main page. But this is not the real last post.

**Update** - This is the full version, i have also used the restore_current_blog():

```
<?php

    $blogs = get_last_updated(' ', 0, 1);
    foreach ($blogs AS $blog);
        switch_to_blog($blog["blog_id"]);
            $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=1&orderby=date');
            foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?> 
    <div class="container-img">
     <a class="anteprima_princ" href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID); ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('immagine-principale'); ?></a>
     </div>
                <h2 class="entrytitlepost"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                  <div class="post-content-princ">
        <p><?php the_content_rss('...', FALSE, '', 40); ?></p>
        <div id="lt">
        <div id="leggitutto"><div id="croce"><div id="alto"></div><div id="largo"></div></div><a class="lt" href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">LEGGI TUTTO</a></div>
      </div>
      </div>

         <?php endforeach ; ?>

                        <?php restore_current_blog(); //switched back to main site ?>
```

Comment: You might consider using [`update_site_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_site_option) to set a site option when a new post is added. You should be able to hook it to the appropriate [Post Status Transition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) (perhaps `new_to_publish`). That way you don't have to do a whole pile of `switch_to_blog()` / `restore_current_blog()` calls -- your post's info (ie, ID) can be stored in the site option.

Comment: @PatJ thank you for your advice, can you show me your version of code for fix mine?

Comment: What exactly does not work with the solution I posted? Have you tried just editing the `orderby`?

Comment: I have only edited the orderby and if i save like this i see white page...

Comment: My mistake, miss a ); . But still doesn't work, because when i refresh a post it became the last post, but this is not really the last post. Is the last updated.

Comment: Your `foreach()` should terminate with a `:`, not a `;`. If that's a typo, fine; if it's in your code, you need to fix it.

Comment: No, but the code now works.. the problem is that doesn't do what i want. I try to explain me better (my english is bad, sorry), this is the site (www.studionews24.com) and the main post with image is get with the code above. The problem is the difference between last post and last post updated. With the code of @fischi i have the same problem.

Comment: I don't wanna that if i update a post the post comes like last post.

Answer (score 3):

The `orderby`-parameter should be `post_date` instead of date.

your code would look something like this:

```
$blogs = get_last_updated(' ', 0, 1);
foreach ($blogs AS $blog) {
    switch_to_blog($blog["blog_id"]);
    $args = array(
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'numberposts'     => 1,
        'post_type'       => 'post',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );
    $lastposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach($lastposts as $thispost) {

        setup_postdata($thispost);

    }
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Please do not forget to call `restore_current_blog()` in your `foreach`. If you used `switch_to_blog()` more than once before calling `restore_current_blog()`, it won't work anymore.

Comment: +1 for the `restore_current_blog()` reminder.

Comment: @PatJ this should be the standard footer of every multisite answer :D

Comment: I have tried to readapt your code in my case, but seems not working. I upload the full code so you can see more clearly what is my problem ok?

Comment: @fischi i have update my question. I have included the rest of html and php.

Comment: Did you try deactivating all your plugins? Maybe one of them interferes with your Query.

Comment: Yes have try but it works like the same code that i had, the last post updated and not really the last post.

Comment: Please check your database if the times for modified and published are correct. Otherwise I'm quite at the end of my ideas ;)

Answer (score 2):

*@fischi's answer appears to answer the question you asked; I suggest this only as an alternative.*

You can create/update a site option every time a new post is published:

```
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'wpse133433_latest_post' );
function wpse_133433_latest_post( $post ) {
    $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
    $latest = array( 
        'blog_id' => $blog_id,
        'post_id' => $post->ID,
    );
    update_site_option( 'latest_post_in_network', $latest );
}
```

Then, to check it:

```
$latest = get_site_option( 'latest_post_in_network' );
// should return an array with blog_id and post_id
```

#### References

- [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)
- [`update_site_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_site_option)
- [`get_site_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option)

#### Notes

- You need the first code block to run on *every* site in your network (that you want to collect posts from) -- you can make it into a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) or a network-enabled plugin.
- You may need to hook to more than one Post Transition hook -- ie, `draft_to_publish`, `pending_to_publish`, etc.
- The `$latest` array in the first code block can hold more info, too. You could, for example, add the current time, so that when you do your `get_site_option()`, you've immediately got access to the latest update's time as well as its `blog_id` and `post_id`.